# Proportion across rows and specific columns in R

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics

I want to get a proportion of pcr detection and create a new column using the following test dataset. I want a proportion of detection for each row, only in the columns pcr1 to pcr6. I want the other columns to be ignored.

```
  site sample pcr1 pcr2 pcr3 pcr4 pcr5 pcr6
pond 1      1 1    1    1    0    1    1
pond 1      2 1    1    0    0    1    1
pond 1      3 0    0    1    1    1    1
```

I want the output to create a new column with the proportion detection. The dataset above is only a small sample of the one I am using. I've tried:

```
data$detection.proportion <- rowMeans(subset(testdf, select = c(pcr1, pcr2, pcr3, pcr4, pcr5, pcr6)), na.rm = TRUE)
```

This works for this small dataset but I tried on my larger one and it did not work and it would give the incorrect proportions. What I'm looking for is a way to count all the 1s from pcr1 to pcr6 and divide them by the total number of 1s and 0s (which I know is 6 but I would like R to recognize this in case it's not inputted).

Comment: Are the columns in your full dataframe `site`, `sample`, and then all your `pcr` columns?

Comment: @sumshyftw yes they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it in case anyone else needed to. I don't know if this is the most effective but it worked for me.

```
data$detection.proportion <- length(subset(testdf, select = c(pcr1, pcr2, pcr3, pcr4, pcr5, pcr6)))
#Calculates the length of pcrs = 6

p.detection <- rowSums(data[,c(-1, -2, -3, -10)] == "1") 
#Counts the occurrences of 1 (which is detection) for each row 

data$detection.proportion <- p.detection/data$detection.proportion
#Divides the occurrences by the total number of pcrs to find the detected proportion.
```